# Azure App Service SSL Certificate Not Trusted

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=recruit.equitysim.ai

### Situation:

- A client needs to access our site over a secure connection but is unable to do so because of a problem with our certificate.
- We purchased a wildcard certificate and set it up as per the documentation. If you notice in the provided link, our certificate is trusted.
- We are using the Azure App Service to host our website on a paid level that includes custom domain and SSL support.

### Problem:

- According to the test, it appears that Microsoft's SSL certificate is not trusted - alternative names mismatch (See Certificate #2). We believe this to be the reason why our client is unable to access our site.

Any thoughts on the matter? We know it isn't an SNI problem because we have another site that is hosted on a VM that also requires SNI support and they can visit that site just fine.

Comment: Did you forget to set the SSL binding in the Azure Portal? It is not enough to just upload the certificate, you have to bind it to one or more Web Apps. Else the default Microsoft SSL certificate will get served, which naturally does not match your custom domain name.

Comment: @evilSnobu it has definitely been bound. The situation is still unresolved at the moment but I think the real problem is the client's corporate network is using a tool to block external sites that aren't categorized (our site is fairly new). We are waiting to see if whitelisting our site will solve the current problem. The initial response we had back when the client first visited the site was that it was restricted because it wasn't secure (which it was).

Comment: The only way they can get the Microsoft cert instead of yours is by NOT passing the domain name in the TLS handshake (in the SNI extension). So yes, a man-in-the-middle something (probably enterprise proxy or security mumbo-jumbo device) could be part of that problem.